# Issue How to track each size of product inventory

Tags: magento-1.9, cataloginventory

I have a question.

Please let me know how I can do this? We cannot count inventory for variations, like XL, XM, M, L etc.. etc..

For example, take a look at this product, it has different size "select size" A0 A4, and A5. These are all different sizes. How do we keep track of the inventory of this "A0, A4, A5" etc..-->

Please have a look on the link of site, Where you can see product having different sizes so I want to track each size of inventory .. http://162.144.88.25/~sjjif/breakpointfc/index.php/break-point-ultra-light-standard-blue-pants.html I want to know this only?

Tracking: I want tracking like if I have 10 - A0 size of product define somewhere in admin like we define inventory for simple product and customer purchased 2 product of A0 size and inventory will auto decrease after successfully make payment ..

---

yes .. Right now the size drop down that you are seen on the product page is created from custom options of each product.

So you mean I need to create the configurable products like define on the following link http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

After creating all configurable products I can track each size of product. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track inventory if you use configurable products, with simple products for each variation. Are you currently using custom options? If so, then you cannot track inventory for those.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's an extension floating around for that, having all those simple products are just a pain plus there is the question about performance. We primarily use custom options with this functionality, it keeps everything in one place and is many times simpler to maintain from a business perspective.

Comment: Is there any extension available for make the products to configurable. If yes Please give me link for extension because I have more than 250 products available in my store, If I make each product configurable one by one it take too much time. thanks ..

Comment: Your best bet is to reload them via Magmi, 250 is a very low number of products so a configurable would be better in your particular case than the expense of an extension.